# Multiple OR operation on one var

Tags: php, regex

I want to select multiple value on the same variable in a if
like

```
if ($var == "1|3|5")
{ Echo'The var was 1,3 or 5';}
```

is this possible without the usual long way

```
$var == "1" or $var == "3" or $var == "5"
```

it should not contains the value like 13 in 113. It should check the hole variable in a string

Comment: If you strong the values in an array you could use `in_array`. If you store those in a string you could use it in `preg_match`. e.g. `if (preg_match('/^1|3|5$/', $var))`

Comment: PERFECT that was im looking for ^ and $ with preg_match in front. Thx so much.

Comment: You actually should group the values. The anchors currently only affects the lead and closing value. `^(1|3|5)$`.